# Assign UPN to Azure Active Directory Application Registration

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I have application registered in Azure Active directory, we use app id and secret to access different resources, here is sample code to request access token

```
var authority = $"https://login.windows.net/TENANT_ID";
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TokenCache.DefaultShared);
var clientCred = new ClientCredential("APP_ID", "APP_SECRET");
var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("RESOURCE_ID", clientCred);
Console.WriteLine(result.AccessToken);
```

However one of the systems requires us to include UPN in access token, is it possible? Is it possible to assign some UPN to Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, *you can't* assign a UPN to an application.

You are authenticating against Azure using a Service Principal. A Service Principal also have a name - the SPN but not a User Principal Name.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Upn(UserPrincipalName claim) is automatically included if user interaction involved(such as [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code)). You can [decode](https://jwt.io/) the access token to find it.

[image]

However, for client credential flow, this parameter won't exist.